# How to Send Mouse Movements and Clicks from Android to Desktop

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, mouse-cursor

I want to make an app (Android Studio and Java) that can control a desktop mouse cursor via Bluetooth.

How would I go about doing this? Are there any functions to control the cursor of a device connected via BT? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to phrase your question such that it fits SO guidelines. This problem as it currently stands is too broad/primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

It is a late answer but one solution would be designing the architecture like:

- An application that is capable of reading the touch input using the `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` and recording the previous and current values and computing the difference sending it through a bluetooth UDP client to a server.

  > ```
  > @Override
  > public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent e)
  > {
  >
  >    switch(e)
  >    {     
  >         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
  >             float initX = e.getX();        
  >             float initY = e.getY();
  >             return true;
  >
  >         case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:        
  >             float curX = initX - e.getX();
  >             float curY = initY - e.getY();
  >             sendThroughUDP(curX, curY);
  >             return true; 
  >     }
  > }
  > ```
- A Server running on your desktop capable of reading this. For example a simple java UDP server over bluetooth which is possible as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1046688/3086235). This will receive these values and then inject these values to the `Robot` class if Java.

> ```
>  //implement the UDP over the bluetooth stack.
>  public static void main(String [] args)
>  {
>       UDPOverBluetoothServer UDPBT = new UDPOverBluetoothSever(socketInformation);
>       int xValue = UDPBT.getX();          
>       int yValue = UDPBT.getY();
>       Robot robot = new Robot();
>       Point mousePointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
>       robot.mouseMove(mousePointer.x - xValue, mousePointer.y - yValue); 
>  }
> ```